# Disable `std::cout` but keep Unity prints on embedded device which prints over SWO/USART

Tags: c++, cout

We are doing some testing directly on the embedded device and are printing *"custom formatted"* test results over USART or SWO using `std::cout`.

Our embedded device uses a custom definition of `_write` which redirects all the prints to USART or SWO:

```cpp
//======================================================================================================================
//! @brief  Redirects the underlying write call (called by printf for instance) to write to the UART or SWO interface
//======================================================================================================================
int _write(int file, char* ptr, int len)
{
  for (std::uint16_t idx = 0; idx < len; idx++)
  {
    // SWO
    if (g_kEnableSWO)
    {
      ITM_SendChar(*ptr);
    }
    // UART
    if (nullptr != g_pUart)
    {
      // Here we call a custom USART driver function that transmits a single character.
    }
    ptr++;
  }
  return len;
}
```

Now, this worked great for us and everything that we printed with `std::cout` was also seen on USART or SWO.

---

We are now migrating from the "custom formated" test results to the Unity ([link](https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Unity)) which also has prints of its own. *"Unity formated"* test results were not printed over USART or SWO until we provided three custom definition that enable Unity to compile and print on embedded:

```cpp
//======================================================================================================================
//! @brief This extern "C" block is needed by Unity framework which fails to compile if these definitions are missing.
//======================================================================================================================
extern "C"
{
  // Unity executes this before each test.
  void setUp(void)
  {
  }

  // Unity executes this after each test.
  void tearDown(void)
  {
  }

  // Unity needs this definition to be able to print anything.
  void unityPrintChar(int character)
  {
    putchar(character);
  }
}
```

Unity works and now we have an output which is a mix of our *"custom formated"* test results and *"Unity formatted"* test results. At this moment I could remove all the `std::cout` statements from the code and be done with, but we decided that it is good to keep the prints for debugging and enable them using some sort of a define.

I tried implementing this define like shown below together with replacing all the `std::cout` with `MY_COUT`.

```
//======================================================================================================================
// Disable/enable std::cout() prints.
//======================================================================================================================         
#ifdef ENABLE_STD_COUT
  #define MY_COUT std::cout
#else
  class NullBuffer : public std::streambuf {
  public:
      int overflow(int c) override {
          return traits_type::not_eof(c); // Do nothing
      }
  };
  
  class NullStream : public std::ostream {
  public:
      NullStream() : std::ostream(&nullBuffer) {}
  private:
      NullBuffer nullBuffer;
  };
  
  #define MY_COUT NullStream()
#endif
```

However, this changes nothing... All the prints are still printed. Any ideas why?